You must call the Bind method before performing this operation => No, I don't
I'm working on two applications (a server one and a client one), both communicating with each other via TCP port 7447.
The server application is already running and is connected on the mentioned port:
Prompt>netstat -aon | findstr "7447"
  UDP    0.0.0.0:7447           *:*                                    41316

Prompt>tasklist /FI "PID eq 41316"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
       MyServer.exe          41316 Console                    1     71.308 K

In the client application, I'm trying to receive information from the server application, as follows:
private void Receive()
{
    BaseTelegram telegram = null;
    IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this._listenPort);
    try
    {
        Byte[] receivedBytes = this._udpClient.Receive(ref endpoint);

The mentioned _udpClient has following properties:

I also know it has passed via this source code:
public UdpConnection(System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient udpClient, Int32 listenPort)
{
    this._listenPort = listenPort;
    this._udpClient = udpClient;
}

I know for a fact that the client application is running at customer's site, but on my PC, I get the following exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'You must call the Bind method before performing this operation.'

I'm not interested in how I should adapt the source code in order to make it work (as the code is working at customer's premises, it should work on my PC too), I'd like to know which configuration I need to alter in order to make this code work.

first of all I would point out you are actually using UDP not TCP... but it's just a minor clarification. Such expection you described is probably thrown when attempting to read the stream from the udp connection that wasn't estabilished and that you are not checking for before using. The reason why the connection doesn't get estabilished in your local scenario is maybe related to the fact that port is already busy in your machine or you have firewalls preventing outbound traffic

@DiegoD: thanks for your quick reply, but I'm seriously doubting that the problem is general on my computer: that same port is used for all our client-server programs. Now when one such a program is running, it automatically blocks others from being started. If I try something similar (with more recent applications), everything is working fine.

It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than just two snippets. I'd recommend a console app that you expect to be able to receive data, but which fails in the same way as your real application. I wouldn't expect us to have to be running a server ourselves in order to see the problem. (The Receive call would just hang or eventually time out.) It would also be good to know about more than just your PC and one customer's PC - do colleagues see the same behavior as your PC, or your working customer? What about other customers?

Also, FYI; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.exclusiveaddressuse?view=net-9.0

If you do not specify a port parameter when constructing a UdpClient, then the client will not be bound to a local port, and you cannot call the Receive method. For example:
this._udpClient = new UdpClient();
var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this._listenPort);
// You must call the Bind method before performing this operation.
this._udpClient.Receive(ref endpoint);

This behaviour is mentioned in the document:

Before calling ReceiveFrom, you must explicitly bind the Socket to a local endpoint using the Bind method. If you do not, ReceiveFrom will throw a SocketException.

The direct solution is to specify a port parameter when constructing the UdpClient (0 is also possible):
this._udpClient = new UdpClient(0);

Another implicit solution is to call the Send method before calling the Receive method, that's because the underlying service provider will assign the most appropriate local network address and port number.
this._udpClient = new UdpClient();
this._udpClient.Send(data, dataLength, remoteEP); // This turns out to be 
                                                  // the final solution.
....
this._udpClient.Receive(ref endpoint);


You are right: the Send() indeed forces that binding, and everything seems to be find now. The real issue was that the IP address of the customer system was hardcoded in the remoteEP you mentioned in the parameters of the Send() method, causing the Send() to fail, causing the binding to fail, .... By replacing remoteEP by 127.0.0.1, the problem is solved (and by stating that the debugger should not always break when an exception occured during reception of messages).
